# For each $x \geq 6$ there exists a prime $p$ such that, $x - 1 > p > 1$ and $p$ does not divide $x$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Here is the proof that I have constructed. I am basically wondering if this proof works. Also feel free to post any simpler proofs or improvements/critiques on this one.

Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ be such that $x \geq 6$. Now suppose for the sake of contradiction we have that all the primes less than $x$, $2 , \cdots , p_n$ , $p_i | x$. Notice here that $p_n$ is the largest prime is less than $x$. Since $(p_i , p_j) = 1$ for each $i,j \in [1,n]$ such that $i \neq j$, we have $2\cdot 3 \cdots p_n | x$. Thus $x \geq 2 \cdot 3 \cdots p_n$. Consider $3\cdot 4 \cdots p_n - 2 = P$. It is easily verified that if $x \geq 6$ we have $x-1 > P > p_n$. Since $P$ P is less than $x$ it must be divisible by some $p_i$. $P$ is not divisible by 2, since it is 2 less than some product of odd numbers. If $p_i | P$ then $p_i| (3\cdots p_i \cdots p_n - P)$. Since $3\cdots p_i \cdots p_n - P = 2$ we have $p_i | 2$ which implies $p_i = 2$ which is a contradiction. Thus there must exist some prime less than $x-1$ that does not divide $x$.

Comment: but for $x=6$ the primes $1<p<5$ are $2$ and $3$, and they both divide $6$, or did I misunderstood something in your statement?

Comment: You're right. The error is when i assume we have that all primes less than $x$ when i really should be assuming all primes less than $x - 1$. Thank you very much

Comment: With the correction x-1 ≥ p > 1 this is true for every x ≥ 3.

Comment: I would say that any counterexample x would have to be a multiple of the product of all primes < x. If every prime p < 6 divides x then x is a multiple of 30. If every prime p < 30 divides x then x is a multiple of 6,469,693,230. If every prime p < 6,469,693,230 divides x then x is pretty big :-)

Comment: You might want to research Bertrand theorem.  If all p < x-1 divide x then if q is the largest prime less than x-1 then x = kp.  And between p and kp - 1 = x-1, there aren't any primes.  Bertrand theorem has something to say about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supose $x\geq 5$, then every prime that divides $x-2$ also divides $x$, notice that if a prime divides $x$ and $x-2$ then that prime is $2$. We conclude that $x-2$ is a power of $2$, the same reasoning shows $x-4$ is also a power of $2$.

Since $x-4$ and $x-2$ are powers of $2$ we conclude $x=6$, and $x=6$ is the only counterexample larger than $4$.

Comment: this argument works for $x\geq 5$. Notice that the claim is not true for $x=4$.